# Are the :text, :radio, :checkbox, etc selectors still deprecated in 1.9.0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, deprecated

I had stopped using `:text` and `:radio` since they were [deprecated in 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9400). However, I noticed that as of 1.9.0, there is [no longer any indication](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) that they're deprecated. [Here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/3e40b5d6055c192925a28efbd6c4abf5c784508e/sizzle.js#L1316) is the relevant Sizzle code that was included in 1.9.0.

Also, [searching for 'deprecated' in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/?s=deprecated) gives no indication of their deprecation.

Comment: Looks like they still working in jQuery 2.0b1 http://jsfiddle.net/T2Gm8/1/

Comment: I can't find a specific deprecation list for jQuery, but it seems like these selectors still work in 1.9 and will continue to work in 2.0.  I would still suggest avoid using them though; at least for now.

Comment: There is no mention of deprecation in the docs so it's safe to assume that they haven't been deprecated. (Also doesn't seem to be any comments in the code either). [Deprecated 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/), [Release notes 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/), [Release notes 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.9/)

Comment: @MattR - Thanks, that's more clarification. Want to put that as an answer? What's weird is the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) for 1.8 had the issue I linked to about their deprecation. But they're not categorized as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mention in the documentation that `:text` or `:radio` is deprecated in 1.9. I also haven't seen any mention of them being deprecated in the development source.

It is safe to assume that they haven't been deprecated base on the following resources:

- [Release notes 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.8/)
- [Deprecated list 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)
- [Release notes 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.9/)